# jquery clear setTimeout inside each on mouseleave

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each

How to clear setTimeout function which it runs inside each function on mouseover

Here's simple code

```
var timer;

function Close() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(child).css({left:0});
}

$(element).mouseover(function() {
    $(child).each(function(i) {
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
                        $(child).eq('+i+').stop().animate({left:300});
                    }, 350 * (i + 1))
    });
})

$(element).mouseleave(function() {
    Close()
})
```

It works fine, but the problem is when mouse moves quickly before complete animation, they won't stop and back to default position first because setTimeout function unfinished of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
function Close() {
    $(child).each(function() {
        window.clearTimeout($(this).data('timerId')); //clear it here
    }).css({left:0});
}

$(element).mouseenter(function() {
    $(child).each(function(i) {
          var timer =  window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $(child).eq(i).stop().animate({left:300});
                    }, 350 * (i + 1));

          $(this).data('timerId', timer); //save timer id here
    });
})

$(element).mouseleave(function() {
     Close();
});
```

Also note that the pair event for `mouseover` is `mouseout` not `mouseleave` (which is the pair for `mouseenter`).

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWMVn/)**

Here is another version which clears animation (Not sure what you are looking for)

```
   function Close() {

        $child.each(function () {
            window.clearTimeout($(this).data('timerId')); //clear it here
        });

        $child.stop(true, true, true).css({left:0}); //clear the queues and reset the position
    }

$(element).mouseenter(function () {
    $child.each(function (i) {
        var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $child.eq(i).stop().animate({
                left: '300px'
            });
        }, 350 * (i + 1));

        $(this).data('timerId', timer); //save timer id here
    });
})

$(element).mouseleave(function () {
    Close();
});
```

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aY9dz/)***

Comment: Added a second version as well.

Comment: try to move mouse quickly to understand what i mean